# why is my vs code cursor not modifying the text and have a terminal effect

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim

my vs code cursor is BROKEN.

vs code cursor is a block and I can't modify any documents. I typed some code but no change is made to the document.

Here is an image for refrence:

[image]

Comment: do you have the vim plugin installed?

Comment: I think. how does it affect the cursor?

Comment: It works! how does it affect the cursor?

Comment: the cursor basically behaves the same was as if youe were working with a vim editor. if you type an `i` the cursor will change and you will be able to edit the file. in the lower left corner you should somewhere see the string `insert`. by pressing `esc` the cursor will change again and no typing will be possible. either have a look at a vim tutorial or uninstall the plugin.

Comment: thanks. I understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I was using vim. DO NOT USE VIM IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING. vim is great because it allows you to work faster, but for someone how doesn't know the shortcuts, this is extremely terrifying and should not be touched. Another thing I have learnt is that installing random extensions when you start your coding journey and give your future self a headache is a bad idea. But if you insist on using Vim, then please visit their [official documentation](https://www.vim.org/docs.php). If you don't want to read boring text and instead want to play with Vim, then check out [Vim adventures](http://vim-adventures.com/)

### Here is how you disable vim in VS Code:

- Oh no! Vim!

[image: Oh no! Vim!]

- Quick! Disable!

[image: Quick! Disable!]

- Reload!

[image: Reload!]

- Much better!

[image: Much better!]

### And here is how you disable it in IntelliJ products(appCode in the images):

- Oh no! Vim!

[image: Oh no! Vim!]

- ⌘, > Plugins

[image: ⌘,]

- > Installed

[image: Installed]

- Click the check-box of the extension you want to disable(Vim)

[image: Click]

- Restart

[image]

- Much better!

[image]